# How to add menu options to the right side of each expandable list view item in android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Like "Messenger" app, there is an option menu for each of the list view item on the right side. But I want to add the options menu to the right side of each of the expandable list view item. I searched and googled everywhere, but I didn't find any solution. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Messenger:**

[image: **Messenger**]

**activity_category_list.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#009999"
tools:context="com.remindme.sayem.remindme.CategoryList"
>

<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/categoryListView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:divider="#ffffff"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**categoyry_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp"
android:background="#009999"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"

    android:text="Large Text"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/categoryItem" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_name.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:numeric="decimal"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/itemName" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**category_item_menu.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>



<item
    android:title="menus"
    android:id="@+id/menus"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    >
    <item
        android:title="Edit"
        android:id="@+id/editMenu"
        />
    <item
        android:title="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/deleteMenu"
        />

</item>

</menu>
```

Comment: you try to PopupMenu its solve your problem

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Actually where should I use the PopupMenu and which layout should be inflated for this action? If you can give any code segment for this problem, it would be very helpful to me. Cause I googled everywhere and found nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for open option menu using PopupMenu

```
 private void showPickMenu(View anchor) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, anchor);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.new_menu);

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu1
                    //do something here...    
                        break;
                    case R.id.menu2:

                        //do something
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }
```

and your R.menu.new_menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:title="@string/menu1"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu2
        android:title="@string/menu2"></item>

</menu>
```

you have to click your view t to pass in this method

```
showPickMenu(your_view);
```

**Edit**

change your categoyry_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#009999"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Large Text"

        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/fa_ellipsis_v"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and **@string/fa_ellipsis_v** is a awesome font other wise you have to use also imageview

and this **tv_menu** id use in your java code and pass to this method showPickMenu(tv_menu)

and use my menu xml file

Comment: see this demo for Popup Menu : http://javatechig.com/android/android-popup-menu-example

Comment: you have to three dots click to open menu right na?

Comment: okay you try above method and menu/xml file its help you
method to pass your three dots view in method parameter

Comment: I tried your method. But it doesn't give me the three dots view. The popup menu appears when the list item is clicked. I am really grateful for your help but I want that three dots on the right side of each list item. :)

Comment: your item_view layout to put three dots view and click it other wise shoe me your item_view layout...

Comment: okay, Saif. I have uploaded the ".xml" files. Please check above. :)

Comment: thank you so much Saif. your code worked for me. I really appreciate your help. I upvoted your answer and accepted it. And please don't forget to upvote my question. :)